# Testing Enterprise Web Application using Selenium(TestNG)

Tags: java, eclipse, email, security, selenium

I have been working as a Manual Tester from the past 4.5 months and now slowly moving to Automation Testing. I am supposed to automate a Enterprise Web Application using Selenium Web driver in java using Eclipse framework. I have started with the login page for the application which requires Single-Sign On Login. The application needs Symantec VIP security to confirm the identity. The things that is to be automated is  :

1. The application sends the security code to Enterprise mail ID.
2. Selenium Web Driver should open the Enterprise Mail website get the
   content of the mail and read the security code and write
   it on the security code textbox on the login page of the application.
3. Enterprise Mail Website again have Symantec Validation which sends the
   security code to registered mobile number. Selenium Web Driver has to get
   the security code sent to mobile number(which is where I am stucked badly)
   and write it on the security code textbox after which scenario 2 needs to
   be automated.

I have configured Java Mail API jar files into my Eclipse but I do not have any idea on how to move forward. Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: @Haxor-I am unable to join the chat...

Comment: now your can do it